# kivy- How to make a widget spin?

Tags: geometry, kivy, spinning

SO ive got this code, but now i need it to spin with different speed( is because i got 6 of those with different length ) and different directions. so if anyone could please help me as ive been trying to do that for more than a month

```
<BOXc>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            circle:
                (1150, 480, min(self.width, self.height)
                / 3, 0, 264)
```

Comment: Welcome new contributor, I'm reviewing first posts. Might be worth posting the code your have, gives it a bit of context as answers and assistance tend to be direct code, rather than a discussion.

Comment: Use Rotate canvas instructions. Beyond that, post an example demonstrating a specific problem that you have.